# json and json array android

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

This is my json data string http://falerooz.ir/output_fal.php

```
 try {
        JSONArray tasks = new JSONArray(G.json_file);
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = tasks.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = object.getString("id");
            String farvardin = object.getString("farvardin");
            String ordibehesht = object.getString("ordibehesht");
            String khordad = object.getString("khordad");
            String tir = object.getString("tir");
            String mordad = object.getString("mordad");
            String shahrivar = object.getString("shahrivar");
            String mehr = object.getString("mehr");
            String aban = object.getString("aban");
            String azar = object.getString("azar");
            String dey = object.getString("dey");
            String bahman = object.getString("bahman");
            String esfand = object.getString("esfand");
            String startdate = object.getString("startdate");
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

my Error :

```
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at com.aradmobile.MainActivity.fal(MainActivity.java:416)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at com.aradmobile.MainActivity.chek_update(MainActivity.java:923)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at com.aradmobile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:206)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-24 17:44:51.810: W/System.err(1310):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at com.aradmobile.MainActivity.fal(MainActivity.java:416)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at com.aradmobile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:217)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-24 17:44:51.814: W/System.err(1310):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you show me your structure Json ?

Comment: you can see in this page :  http://falerooz.ir/output_fal.php

Comment: The string you're trying to parse is probably empty. You should dump it to see what it looks like, maybe the JSON string is null...

Comment: i got log it ,  it is not null :(

Comment: What is line 416 of your mainactivity?

Comment: first of all check your response is not empty? print a log with your response.  It works well??

Comment: private void fal(){  in line 416

Comment: Yes i print log it not empty i am sure my G.json_file have json from my page corectlly

Comment: It doesn't seem correct that you parse the key of ```ushahrivarrl``` using ```object.getString("shahrivar");```.

Comment: yes i corret it but yet i have this erors

Comment: Do you have the json local or are you getting from the link?
If local, show us the toString() of ```G.json_file```
If network, check your connection.

Comment: Are you downloading the json and save it locally?

Comment: i download and save it to String

Comment: Post that String as you've written it.
Also post your file writing and reading logic.

Comment: So why are you using JSONArray tasks = new JSONArray(G.json_file); , I think It could be JSONArray tasks = new JSONArray(yourString);

Comment: Could you please detail which of the lines on the code you posted is line 416?

Comment: @es0329 `object.getString("shahrivar");.` is the correct android Syntax.

Comment: @user5253549, try to send the array without encoding it.

Comment: @mdamia Yes, the syntax is right, but at the time of my post ```"shahrivar"``` was the wrong key. Soon-after he corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exception indicate the error is occurring on "JSONArray tasks = new JSONArray(G.json_file);"

Please check the file content which you used to save the JSON download from the internet.

I just copy/paste your json string into my code and use the String object to generate the JSONArray. It works. BUT, when I want to print the JSON, I found there might be some non-character value in the JSON and interrupt the output.

""mordad": "\r\n\r\nتصور شما از بهشت، اين است كه همه چيز به آرامي پيش رود و تا آن جا كه مي توانيد دست به انجام كاري نزنيد. تنها امروز، كمي تنبل شده ايد و نمي توانيد از انرژي خود بهره جسته و خود را نشان دهيد، مگر اين كه واقعاً نياز به اين كار باشد. اگر احساس خستگي مي كنيد، ممكن است زود به رختخواب برويد تا فردا صبح با روحيه اي بهتر و شا�"

So, my guess is :
1. there is some wrong-format character in the text.
2. When you save the string into file, it was truncated.
3. At the end, you tried to create JSONArray by using the String which is restored from the truncated file. It leads to an error.

My suggestion is :
1. check the file content/length, make sure the file is same to the network
2. or you can try to use the content download from network directly, if it solves the problem, you can locate/narrow the issue area